# Выпадающий список с возможностью дописать текст

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Доброго времени суток, знатоки! Появилась необходимость сделать необычный выпадающий список. У меня есть поле, куда юзер будет вбивать свой сотовый телефон. И мне нужно, чтобы при клике на поле выпадал список с уже прописанными индексами сотовых операторов вроде +7 700, +7 701 т.д. После номера, разумеется, нужно дописать свой номер до конца. Тут и проблема. Идеально бы подошел на эту роль datalist, но увы - он сохраняет только значение value у option'а... Я представляю, как можно решить эту проблему, но получится громоздко. Может, кто-нибудь знает иной способ попроще? Или плагин какой-нибудь? Я ничего не нашел... Заранее спасибо!)

Comment: Посмотрите [select2][]. Даже если это не совсем то, не его основе можно сделать то =)

  [select2]: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: Обосновать *необходимость* можете? По вашему описанию, вы собрались сделать самый неудобный элемент ввода из тех, которые можно представить.

Comment: С точки зрения юзера - вполне удобный, по-моему. Необходимость в том, что так пожелал заказчик.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:   `http://jsfiddle.net/o4ywfxdq/`

Comment: О, спасибо ! Это уже ближе к истине !)

Comment: @тигрище, это антипаттерн. Вашу форму нельзя заполнить только с клавиатуры. Нельзя заполнить автоматически (roboform и прочие). К тому же кодов для всеразличных операторов будет явно не 5, на 30-40, как минимум, смело можете рассчитывать. Про заказчика - сочувствую.